# Text messaging and calls don't work on Ubuntu Touch dev preview

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sms

I just got Ubuntu Touch on my Galaxy Nexus. I'm really thrilled about its design concepts and its beautiful UI.

However, text messages and calls don't work. Isn't this supposed to work already? Could this be because I'm in Germany?

Maybe this is just a small problem which I can fix myself, does anyone know?

Comment: It a preview, not a finished product, only intended for developers. With no support from mobile carriers, how do you expect SMS and calls should be working?

Comment: I guess I misinterpreted the "What to expect after flashing" Section where it says: "Phone calls and SMS (on Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4)"
Because the dialer works - I can type in a number - there is just no functionality like real calls or anything...

Comment: djfun is right. Calls and SMS work on both the Galaxy Nexus and the Nexus 4 but the sim card must not use a pin because handling of pins is not yet implemented. So just use Android to remove the pin before you try making calls. (Please remember to mark his answer as accepted if it helped)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calls and SMS should work if you use a SIM without PIN code

The important part here: "without PIN code". I would put your sim into another phone and disable the PIN-code. Then put it back into your Ubuntu-Nexus and off you go..